# Java - MySQL Calling Stored Procedure

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, callable-statement

I'm trying to call a Stored Procedure from Java. However, what I did was looking for a Function instead. What did I miss? Here's what I have tried so far;

```
open();

try {

    statement = conn.prepareStatement(StringConstant.PROC_GET_POSITIONS);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

    while( resultSet.next() ){

        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(0));

    }

} catch ( SQLException sqlEx ) {
    sqlEx.printStackTrace();
}

close();
```

Throwing this Exception;

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION test.get_positions does not exist
```

This is how the stored procedure is written (This is for the purpose of testing):

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_positions(OUT o_position VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN

  SELECT pos_name
  INTO o_position
  FROM master_position;

END;
```

The reason I made the question is that SO suggested this titles:

-automate call stored procedure 1
-How to Call a Stored Procedure within a Stored Procedure in MySQL 1
-Calling a Stored Procedure in Hibernate 2
-Call a Stored Procedure From a Stored Procedure and/or using COUNT 2
-mysql stored procedure call hibernate 2

None of those answered my question.

Comment: It is looking for a function instead of the procedure.

Comment: read this maybe it will help http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jccids.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/doc/tjvcscsp.htm

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for the link. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: why are you using a stored procedure when you can execute that query directly?

Comment: The actual stored procedure consist of at least 90 lines. The procedure showed is for testing purposes.

Comment: i see... and you want to call it from java or convert it into a function ?

Comment: I would want to call it from Java. But if it requires converting into a function, I should at least give time for that. I'm new with MySQL, I've been using PostgreSQL for a couple of months and we are migrating the application to MySQL. I have never experienced a problem with PostgreSQL similar to this.

Comment: i don't see any point in converting it into a function, read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html using this you should be able to call the procedure

Comment: I see. If I find this useful, I'll bump you up. Then you may put your comment in answer box so I could consider your answer. Thank you

Comment: Hi Stephan, the link you have given really helped. Please post it as an answer so I could accept.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :D i posted the answer

Answer (score 10):

I'm right now with this problem. I found this:

```java
        Connection conn = getMySqlConnection();
        // Step-2: identify the stored procedure
        String simpleProc = "{ call simpleproc(?) }";
        // Step-3: prepare the callable statement
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(simpleProc);
        // Step-4: register output parameters ...
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        // Step-5: execute the stored procedures: proc3
        cs.execute();
        // Step-6: extract the output parameters
        int param1 = cs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("param1=" + param1);
```

I think this could be a great example.

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CallStoredProcedureInMySql.htm

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to get the result from the stored procedure. Stored procedures do not return values instead Function does.

Comment: Hi Juned, thanks for the reply. I'll update you after trying to convert the procedure into a Function.

Answer (score 2):

```
Statement stmt;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(String.format("CALL swap_devices(%d,%d)", oldDeviceID, newDeviceID));
```

Comment: Using `String.format()` to pass "bind values" to JDBC is a sure way to get SQL injection vulnerabilities. Please never do this, always use `PreparedStatement` and bind values, or use a library that correctly escapes embedded values if you *must* use a static statement.

Comment: When that code was written (9 years ago), that service was not customer-facing. neither of those values passed in were coming from any exposed endpoint nor any human nor 3rd-Party Service. They were populated & executed by a cron-job. So It's still relatively safe to rule out SQL-Injection attack unless otherwise utilised as a subsequent attack prior to another attack eg. heartbleed, log4J attacks. All strings injected via RESTful API were strictly sanitised/scanned.

Comment: To add to the above, you can clearly see that those params are of integer/decimal data type.

Comment: No one will read this big paragraph. Everyone will copy paste the code snippet.